# Linux operating system process management

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

how a new process is created in Linux when fork() is called. location and name of variables through which the process manager keeps track of the following information:


- Total number of processes currently in the system
- Total number of processes created since the system booted
- Maximum number of allowed processes

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total number of processes currently in the system

```
 ps aux | wc -l
```

Total number of processes created since the system booted

```
cat /proc/stat | grep processes
```

Maximum number of allowed processes

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

I am sure there are better tools, but these will 100% on your assignment